# Eclipse: EJB and ManagedBean(for JSF)

Tags: eclipse, ejb, glassfish-3, managed-bean

I'm trying to create some Java EE application. The base is **EJB** as a controller. Next I want to present the data with **JSF+ManagedBeans**. The problem is there is

**javax.servlet.ServletException: standards/SampleController**

**java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: standards/SampleController**

The Code looks like this:

*Managed bean(Dynamic Web Project):WebView project: StdSampleController.java:*

```
import javax.ejb.EJB;

import standards.SampleController;

public class StdSampleController {

    @EJB private SampleController c;
    public String value;

    public StdSampleController() {
        c = new SampleController();
        value = c.getValue();
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }
}
```

*EJB(EJB Project): WebController project: standards.SampleController.java:*

```
package standards;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

/**
 * Session Bean implementation class SampleController
 */
@Stateless
public class SampleController implements SampleControllerRemote {

    private String value;

    public SampleController() {
        value = "EJB:SampleController bean";
    }

    public String getValue(){
        return value;
    }

}
```

All this code is put together in an Enterprise Application Project.
I use GlassFish version 3 and Eclipse 3.5.2.

Answer (score 3):

Adding to the answer of unbeli, please remove the following from your code:

```
public StdSampleController() {
    c = new SampleController();
    value = c.getValue();
}
```

This is wrong. In the situation you're depicting, `c` will be injected by the container with a reference to your EJB. Do not instantiate the EJB yourself via the new() operator.

Answer (score 2):

You call your EJB using the (remote) interface, not it's implementation.
Therefore, instead of

```
@EJB private SampleController c;
```

you need

```
@EJB private SampleControllerRemote c;
```

and adjust imports accordingly.

Comment: Indeed, alternatively don't define an interface at all, or define a local interface since you seem to be calling the EJB bean from within the same JVM.